# Do standalone JavaScript blocks have any use?

Tags: javascript, block

The [MDN article on JavaScript blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) gives this example:

```
var x = 1;
{
  var x = 2;
}
alert(x); // outputs 2
```

As you can see JavaScript doesn't have block scope. So are there any good use cases for standalone blocks in JavaScript?

By "standalone" I mean not paired with a control flow statement (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.) or a `function`.

Comment: Taken from the same article: "Although 'standalone' blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java." I would take their word for it on this one if I were you.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm still curious if they have a use, whether it's a good one or not.

Comment: @BoltClock While that's true, the OP seems to be looking for specific scenarios where people think "Well, I've found block statements are great for ______". I'm not sure there are any, but still :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer: ...not really.

The only use I know for them is labels:

```
myBlock: {
    // stuff
    if (something) break myBlock // jump to end of block
    // more stuff
    if (somethingElse) continue myBlock // jump to beginning of block
    // blah blah blah, more stuff
}
```

(almost like a `goto`, better [watch out for the raptors](http://xkcd.com/292/))

Needless to say, this is a very bad idea. So basically, nothing; just don't use them.

(side note: a `do { /* stuff */ if (something) break; /* stuff */ } while (false)` could do the same thing)

Comment: Wouldn't they still do nothing in that circumstance too?

Comment: @alex No. `break myBlock` will jump to the end of the block.

Comment: @alex What do you mean "nothing"? They provide a "goto"-like scenario. Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/w7A85/

Comment: @Ian I meant, wouldn't control jump to the label anyway, but it seems I am wrong. I didn't realise labels could point to other things than loops.

Comment: "Needless to say, this is a very bad idea" [disputed]

Comment: @Jan The raptors will get you. :P

Answer (score 8):

ES2015 introduces block scoping with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), so standalone blocks become useful for limiting the [scope of variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
{
  let privateValue = 'foo';
}

console.log(privateValue); // -> ReferenceError
```

In contrast to `var`:

```
{
  var privateValue = 'foo';
}

console.log(privateValue); // -> "foo"
```

`let` and `const` are implemented in the latest versions of all major browsers (including IE11).

- [`let` compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let)
- [`const` compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const)